# Convert String(already formatted) to an Array of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, string, nsdictionary

I have this String already formatted as a [[String:AnyObject]], however I can't retrieve the information out of it nor couldn't find a way to convert it to a dictionary.

> [ [name: Laura, age:33, gender: female],  [name: James, age:25,
>   gender:male] ]

What can be done to convert this string into a dictionary?

Comment: The only option you have is to convert the entire string to a valid JSON format. You need to write your own parser using `NSRegularExpression` or by some other means. The rest of the thing should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatted string must be well formatted as an json, then you can use the next code:

```
NSString* str=@"[ {\"name\": \"Laura\", \"age\":33, \"gender\": \"female\"}, {\"name\": \"James\", \"age\":25, \"gender\":\"male\"} ]";
NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray* jsonArr=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonArr);
```